# How to make a conditional to know if it is the first time you run the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to know how to set a conditional: If this is the first time you start the activity (every time you start the application) do something, and if I already began earlier do something else. Something like:

```
If (firstTime) {
}
else {
bundle = getIntent () getExtras ().;
count = bundle.getInt ("countAnterior");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should store a flag for that. for example store a number in `SharedPreferences` to know if it's first time or not.

you can do something like this :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (preferences.getInt("first", 0) != 1) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putInt("first", 1);
  editor.commit();
   //first time
} else {
  // not first time
}
```

Comment: It's what I wanted, but I want to do the same every time I open the application, not just the first time the install. I was looking everywhere but can't find how to make this happen every time I open the application. Anyway,Thanks for your time

Comment: try resetting that value in your `onPause` method and `commit` those changes in `onDestroy` method. but I'm not sure if it works or not!